# Unable to find devices bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, firmware

I am unable to find devices when I turned on my bluetooth

When I do  `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`
 It says

```
[62345.607832] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[62345.608374] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
```

Any idea how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution.
First I did

```
 uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
```

output said

```
Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd not found
bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd failed with error -2
```

So I did

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm
sudo wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd
```

And rebooted the system and now Bluetooth is functional

Answer (score 0):

I got a very similar issue but not the exact same, just for any other person having a similar one.

My solution (notice different driver version):

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm
sudo wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

In case you need a different driver for your Broadcom bluetooth driver, you can check it like this:

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

Try to locate any message about missing driver file, take note about the expected filename:
Then build your custom URL:

*https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/<put_here_your_driver_filename>*

Mine was https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-04ca-2006.hcd